# While I try install 'gem install watir' I get this error

Tags: ruby, watir

While I try to install the watir, I have the following error, Can anyone please guide me how to resolve this problem?

```
 C:\>gem install watir -v 4.0.2
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
host. - SSL_connect (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=watir-webdriver)
```

I am using Ruby 2.1.5 and WATIR 4.0.2.

Comment: This error suggests that you have a network connection failure. Try this command later if you are sure you can access to the internet.

Comment: @Aetherus No, It's getting installed when I try with Ruby 2.0.0 , It's not happening only when I try using Ruby 2.1.4 or Ruby 2.1.5

Comment: I'll try it myself, and see what happens.

Comment: Are you a Chinese guy or working in China? If so, well, the domain `api.rubygems.org` is blocked by the notorious GFW. Try swich the gem sources to `http://ruby.taobao.org/`

Answer (score 10):

Whenever you see the following error:

```
Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

But you can access internet normally, it has a high possibility that your request has been blocked by the Chinese governments' **Great Firewall**.

In such case, you can try changing your DNS settings to `8.8.8.8`(Google) if you are not in China, or you can use Taobao's mirror otherwise.

See [ruby.taobao.org](http://ruby.taobao.org/) for details, if you understand Chinese.

The worst case is that the IP of the server serving the gem is blocked by Great Firewall. It will intercept TCP handshakes by send RST packets to both your browser/client and the server. In such case, you have to use some proxy or VPN to get your job done.

Comment: hi, I am not a Chinese guy, I am an Indian.

Comment: India is China's nabour, right? So you are still possibly using China's DNS service, if you leave your networking auto configured.

Comment: But how does it is getting installed when I try using Ruby 2.0.0?

Comment: If that was the case, then it has to happen for while I install through Ruby 2.0.0,right?

Comment: It turned out that the gems are distributed to different servers with different domain names. Some of them are blocked, some are not. You can run `gem install <some-gem> --verbose` to see which domain is actually serving that gem.

Comment: hi, Thanks, I tried with recent version of Ruby (i.e) 2.2.2, but it throws another error like 
'ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A
'
Can you please let me know what kind of error is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77613/discussion-between-aetherus-and-raj).

Comment: @mayaa rubygem uses amazon aws which is blocked,

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your rails ssl certificate

Comment: Can you provide any link

Comment: hi, thank you, This error has been resolved in Ruby 2.1.6, Actually we do not need to change anything.But if you want to use Ruby 2.1.5, there is a file we need to place in a certain folder and it would work!